# How to make all links on a mediawiki site absolute

Tags: hyperlink, mediawiki, absolute

Our SEO advisor suggested to change all links on the site from relative to absolulte. Is there a good way to make it with some changes in localsettings.php or some extension? 
If no, where should I make the least possible change in mediawiki code?

Comment: What does that have to do with SEO? Any search engine has to understand relative links and I think it would be stupid to treat relative and absolute links differently.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

In `LocalSettings.php`

```
$wgArticlePath = "//site.com/wiki/$1";
```